# Angular4 - how to make CanDeactive guard using dialogService confirmation work with chained observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a `CanDeactive` guard based on the Hero app in the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes).

This guard first checks if my component does not need cleanup, and it immediately returns `false` if so.

Otherwise it shows a confirm dialog to the user. The dialog is provided by this service (identical to the docs):

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

/**
 * Async modal dialog service
 * DialogService makes this app easier to test by faking this service.
 * TODO: better modal implementation that doesn't use window.confirm
 */
@Injectable()
export class DialogService {
  /**
   * Ask user to confirm an action. `message` explains the action and choices.
   * Returns observable resolving to `true`=confirm or `false`=cancel
   */
  confirm(message?: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const confirmation = window.confirm(message || 'Is it OK to leave the page?');

    return Observable.of(confirmation);
  };
}
```

If the user answers 'No' (`false`) to the dialog, then `CanDeactive` also immediately returns false. This is why it has two return types: `Observable<boolean>` and `boolean` (again, as per docs).

```
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    console.log('deactivating');
    // Allow immediate navigation if no cleanup needed
    if (this.template.template_items.filter((obj) => 
         { return !obj.is_completed }).length < 2)
      return true;

    // Otherwise ask the user with the dialog service
    this._dialogService.confirm('You have some empty items.
      Is it OK if I delete them?').subscribe(
      confirm => {
        console.log('confirm is ', confirm);
        if (confirm) return this.onDestroyCleanup().subscribe();
        else return false;
      }
    );
  }
```

Where I differ from the docs is that if the user answers yes (true) to the confirm dialog, I need to do some cleanup and then call my api - which you can see is the line `return this.onDestroyCleanup().subscribe()`.

So I don't want to return true immediately, but first call this method and return true or false from that (false only if the api call failed).

Here is that method, which calls the api and maps the result of the api call to true or false:

```
  onDestroyCleanup():Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('cleaning up');
    this.template.template_items.forEach((item, index) => {
      // insert marker flag to delete all incomplete items
      if (!item.is_completed) {
        this.template.template_items[index]['_destroy'] = true;
      };
    });
    // a final save to remove the incomplete items
    return this._templateService.patchTemplate(this.template).take(1).map(
      result => {
        console.log('cleanup done: ', result);
        return true;
      },
      error => {
        console.log('cleanup done: ', error);
        this._apiErrorService.notifyErrors(error.json());
        return false;
      }
    );
  }
```

Everything works except the user stays on the page when they answer Yes. The console output is:

```
deactivating
confirm is true
cleaning up
cleanup done: [returned json object]
```

Seeing that output I realised that `CanDeactive` is not returning a result, so I changed the last part of the `CanDeactive` to this:

```
    ...same code up to here...
    // Otherwise ask the user with the dialog service
    return this._dialogService.confirm('You have some empty items. 
          Is it OK if I delete them?').map(
      confirm => {
        console.log('confirm is ', confirm);
        if (confirm) this.onDestroyCleanup().subscribe(r => {return r});
        else return false;
      }
    );
  }
```

But I get the same result.

So now I don't know whether I am structuring this correctly or if perhaps my `onDestroyCleanup` code is the thing that is wrong.

**UPDATE**

To help understanding, this code obviously works:

```
// Otherwise ask the user with the dialog service
return this._dialogService.confirm('You have some empty items. Is it 
       OK if I delete them?').map(
  confirm => {
    console.log('confirm is ', confirm);
    if (confirm) return true;
    else return false;
  }
);
```

...because it directly returns either true or false. The problem is how to replace the 'return true' with code that calls another Observable and when that resolves, to return the result of THAT one.

But to illustrate further, this does not work as it says "`Type Observable <false> | Observable<boolean> is not assignable to type boolean | Observable<boolean>`":

```
// Otherwise ask the user with the dialog service
return this._dialogService.confirm('You have some empty items. Is it 
       OK if I delete them?').map(
  confirm => {
    console.log('confirm is ', confirm);
    if (confirm) return Observable.of(true); 
    else return false;
  }
);
```

Comment: For `if (confirm) this.onDestroyCleanup().subscribe(r => {return r});` the `return r` is for the function `r => {return r}` not the outer `confirm => { ... }`. It looks like you were expecting that return to work the same as the `return false` on the next line. Or maybe you just forgot the `return` before `this.onDestroyCleanup().subscribe(...)` but that would return the subscription rather than an observable.

Comment: @bygrace Yes, you have pretty much nailed the problem. The inner return r just goes nowhere, but if I put the return before this.OnDestroyCleanup() then it tries to return the subscription, which obviously I can't do - I need to somehow return the result of that subscription.

Comment: Try switchMap instead of map since you want to return an observable rather than a value. `this._dialogService.confirm(...).switchMap(confirm => confirm ? this.onDestroyCleanup() : Observable.of(false))`.

Comment: @bygrace switchMap and flatMap both work if I change the code as per the answer from LLai https://stackoverflow.com/a/47016509/1028679

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `return this.onDestroyCleanup().subscribe();` in your canDeactivate method, you are returning a subscription, not an observable. Also you need to return a chained observable sequence (with flatMap/mergeMap). This way the canDeactivate method altogether returns an observable that can be subscribed to.

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    console.log('deactivating');
    // Allow immediate navigation if no cleanup needed
    if (this.template.template_items.filter((obj) => 
        { return !obj.is_completed }).length < 2)
        return true;

    // Otherwise ask the user with the dialog service
    return this._dialogService.confirm('You have some empty items. Is it OK if I delete them?')
        // chain confirm observable with cleanup observable
        .flatMap(confirm => {
            console.log('confirm is ', confirm);
            if (confirm) {
                return this.onDestroyCleanup();
            } else {
                return Observable.of(false);
            }
        });
}
```

As you can see, we are now returning a chained observable sequence that the CanDeactivate Guard can subscribe to.

When you do swap out your confirm you can modify your confirm() method to something like

```
confirm(message?: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        // bring up custom confirm message somehow
        customConfirm(message, (confirmation: boolean) => {
            // emit result. This would likely be in a callback function of your custom confirm message implementation
            observer.next(confirmation);
            observer.complete();
        }); 
    });
};
```

Now your confirm is returning an asynchronous implementation with an observable.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would work too, and I tried it already (and now again in case I missed something). This code (your first one) never calls onDestroyCleanup(). The console output never shows 'cleanup done:'

Comment: @rmcsharry does the `console.log('confirm is ', confirm);` get called? and does the `console.log('cleaning up');` within onDestroyCleanup get called?

Comment: Yes, and when it is true, onDestroyCleanup is not called.

Comment: @rmcsharry have you tried my 2nd suggestion? I wonder if having that subscribe in the canDeactivate is causing the issue. (even though your confirm() method is synchronous)

Comment: I need to swap out my own modal at some point (as you guessed!) so the 2nd code is not useful. However, I will try it just to see what happens.

Comment: @rmcsharry ah ok, the more I think about it. That should be the issue. Since you have the confirm() subscribe, you have no way to return the onDestroyCleanup() observable to canDeactivate, so it cannot subscribe to it.

Comment: Yes, that make sense, that is exactly the problem. Your 2nd code works! So now I will try to find out if it works without window.confirm!

Comment: @rmcsharry I've updated my answer. I also included an update to your confirm() method so you can implement a new modal implementation in the future

Comment: thank you so much - especially for that extra bit of code on the confirm method, that would have taken me some time to figure out! :)

Comment: Have you seen the comment from @bygrace in the question about switchMap? I think your code is slightly improved with switchMap since the confirm dialog will only ever emit one value, so by using switchMap we grab that and automatically unsubscribe. Not sure if that makes any real difference but it represents the programming logic 'intent' better (I think).

Comment: @rmcsharry from my understanding switchMap will unsubscribe from the inner observable when the outer observable emits. Since the outer observable only emits once, that particular functionality of switchMap does not get used. So in this case, I am not sure either one is more/less correct.

Comment: I think the auto-subscribe would still get used, but with flatMap both subscriptions would remain 'open'. But I'm not really sure either!